# The script fetched from the database and run it in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible that a script stored in the database and fetch it in the node can be implemented?
For example, reading from files

Comment: Script is just a text. You can simply store it as a text and `eval` it on fetch. But be aware that this is highly insecure and I would not advise doing that. It is highly unlikely that you actually need that.

Comment: Build files is time consuming and slows down service